# R: given a list, return a list of equal-length sublists

Tags: r

The length of each sublist is specified to be `LEN`. All sublists, except possibly the last one, should have exactly LEN elements in the original list.

The input can be a list (of same type elements) or a vector. The output type should correspond.

For instance:

Given `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and `LEN = 2`, the function should return `c(c(1, 2), c(3, 4), c(5))`.

Given `list("", "hi", "world", "R is hard")` and `LEN = 2`, the function should return `list(list("", "hi"), list("world", "R is hard")`.

I am looking for an R-idiomatic way to do this. In other languages a for loop suffices.

Or, since I am a complete newbie to R, the setup of this problem may not be idiomatic in the first place. If so please kindly point it out. However the input is fixed to be a list or a vector.

Thanks!

Comment: You're looking for `split`, I believe.

Comment: Please note that `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` and `c(c(1, 2), c(3, 4), c(5))` are identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @joran mentioned you should have a look at `?split`.
To solve your specific problem:

```
a <- 1:5
n <- length(a)
k <- 2 ## your LEN
split(a, rep(1:ceiling(n/k), each=k)[1:n])
#$`1`
#[1] 1 2
#
#$`2`
#[1] 3 4
#
#$`3`
#[1] 5
```